# CSS width of div if other div exists

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML, I want to specify the width of `.left` only if there is `.right` div in the `.wrapper`, otherwise it should take the full width. For example, if there is `.right` div, then the width of the `.left` should be 300px, otherwise it should be 500px.

I think this can be done using the css `+` selector, but if I am not sure how can I apply on the `.left`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
}

.left{
    width: 300px;
}

.right{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to detect if an element exists withing CSS. You'll have to use javascript to do this. In jQuery you can use the .length == 1 method.

Comment: Have you tried using width: 100% on your left div? How did it work if so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the :only-child selector

```
.left:only-child
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/Vd4Pz/)

If you don't want to use the :only-child selector you could try the following

```
.wrapper
{
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed #00f;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/674/)

Comment: great solution! not supported on older browsers, but screw people that use older browsers ;)

Comment: @Gijs Another way to do this would be to set the ``display`` of the wrapper class to ``table`` and the ``display`` of the left and right class to ``table-cell``. I dont think that would work in ie6 and ie7, but would work in older versions of other browsers

Comment: that's also true but i still like your only-child suggestion better :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using CSS for this, why not using the HTML file?

From your question it seems that you have different HMTL files/output. If you add different classes in the HTML files, you can target them directly in CSS:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="full"></div>
</div>
```

You CSS would contain something like this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}

.left {
    width: 300px;
}

.right {
    width: 200px;
}

.full {
    /* Whatever is required for full width */
}
```

Much easier this way! (Assuming you can change the HTML files/output)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for Veger's solution as well if you control the HTML output.
If not, the `+` selector only works for the latter element, thus with `.left + .right` you can change the right div *if* the left div is present. It doesn't work the other way around.

If you know, you'll *always* have a left div, you might put the right div into the left div and have it float right with a width of 200px.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that CSS can detect if an element exists or not, it is only for the presentation of elements.

You can however use javascript to do this. I will show you a jQuery version of it:

You have an element:

```
<div id="one">
  My diiiv.
</div>
```

And you want to do something if this element exists:

```
$.fn.exists = function(callback) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

  if (this.length) {
    callback.call(this, args);
  }
  return this;
};
```

This is a function that will determine if an element exists when it's called.

What you can do now is to test if any element exists:

```
$('div#one').exists(function() {
  this.append('<p>I exist!</p>');
});
```

So if it does, you can augment the DOM in whichever way you want. CSS cannot do this, that's what javascript and its libraries are for :)

http://jsfiddle.net/5Q2Gm/